# How can I give my class a nominal "value" that can be displayed by a variable browser in a debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging

When using debuggers (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for this example), a variable window is often shown giving the names and values of variables in the current scope.

When a value is displayed for a class, it defaults to a format like this: `{a=val1 b=val2 ...}` which isn't always helpful when debugging.

Is there a way, such as operator overloading, that will let me choose what gets shown as a class' "value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for are [Visualizers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx) as long as you are using Visual Studio.

[This](http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83) website has a nice tutorial on them.